# Basic Auth in NodeJs doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I created the following nodejs script,which has to do with basic authentication. I run the server by typing *node server*,so the local url is *localhost:3000*. In my browser,I should be getting a prompt window where I could put the username and password. Instead of it the prompt window doesn't appear and I get a message *Welcome to express*.

```
    var express = require('express');
    var morgan = require('morgan');

    var hostname = 'localhost';
    var port = 3000;

    var app = express();

    app.use(morgan('dev'));

    function auth (req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.headers);
        var authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
        if (!authHeader) {
            var err = new Error('You are not authenticated!');
            err.status = 401;
            next(err);
            return;
        }

        var auth = new Buffer(authHeader.split(' ')[1], 'base64').toString().split(':');
        var user = auth[0];
        var pass = auth[1];
        if (user == 'admin' && pass == 'password') {
            next(); // authorized
        } else {
            var err = new Error('You are not authenticated!');
            err.status = 401;
            next(err);
        }
    }

    app.use(auth);

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use(function(err,req,res,next) {
                res.writeHead(err.status || 500, {
                'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic',
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
            });
            res.end(err.message);
    });

    app.listen(port, hostname, function(){
      console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
    });
```

Any ideas why is this happening?

Thanks,

Theo.

Comment: you must be doing something wrong, as your code works as you expect

Comment: `I get a message Welcome to express` - is that what it says in your default page?

Comment: @Jaromanda X. Yes this is what I get in my default page.

Comment: My package.json is {
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "express-session": "^1.14.1",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "session-file-store": "^0.2.1"
  }
}

Comment: again, your code works as expected - what do you see on the node console

Comment: wow I was running mongodb in another cmd from a previous exercise. I closed it down,and now everything works fine.

Comment: @Theo well, based on your question, mongodb has nothing to do here